# Not uploading image(django-wysiwyg-redactor)

Tags: django, django-admin, wysiwyg

I downloaded [django-wysiwyg-redactor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-wysiwyg-redactor/)

and followed instructions about how to use it.
But when I choose image to upload it doesn't upload. There is no errors.
What's wrong with it?

Here is my article model:
from django.db import models
from redactor.fields import RedactorField

## Create your models here.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'article'

    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    article_text = RedactorField(
        verbose_name=u'Text',
        redactor_options={'lang': 'en', 'focus': 'true'},
        upload_to='tmp/',
        allow_file_upload=True,
        allow_image_upload=True
    )
    article_date = models.DateTimeField()
    article_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from redactor.widgets import RedactorEditor
from article.models import Article
from django import forms

class EntryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        widgets = {
           'article_text': RedactorEditor(),
        }

class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EntryAdminForm
    fields = ['article_title', 'article_text', 'article_date']

admin.site.register(Article, EntryAdmin)
```

Last code line: `admin.site.register(Article, EntryAdmin)` is a little changed, because as instruction says, it must be `admin.site.register(EntryAdminForm, EntryAdmin)`, but in ths case, there is an error:`'ModelFormMetaclass' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0):

Do not specify widget on EntryAdminForm. RedactorField will generate the widget with the right configuration.

```
class EntryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

Comment: What do I need class EntryAdminForm, if I don't use it? Because when I write admin.site.register(EntryAdminForm, EntryAdmin) it cause an error.

Comment: No use like the code you've posted: `admin.site.register(Article, EntryAdmin)`. And as I see you can remove `EntryAdminForm` because it's the same as the automatically generated by Django

Comment: why image doesn't uploads then? I choose image but it loads too long with no result. Maybe I write wrong path to save images?

Answer (score 0):

here is how i got it working

**models.py**

```
from redactor.fields import RedactorField
```

in my model

```
text = RedactorField(verbose_name=u'Text')
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'redactor',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog',
)

REDACTOR_OPTIONS = {'lang': 'en'}
REDACTOR_UPLOAD = 'static/'
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^redactor/', include('redactor.urls')),
```

**admin.py**

```
from django import forms
from redactor.widgets import RedactorEditor

class EntryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    widgets = {
       'text': RedactorEditor(),
    }
    fields = '__all__'

class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EntryAdminForm
```